# Find text of a <li> in a dynamic <ul> on button click Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am populating a list of friends using an ajax call to a php script that returns a json array . I am populating each list item with the friends name and putting a button next to it. The name and the button are both in the list item. I want to find the friends name when i click on the button so I can then post it to another script that will remove them from the friends list. As well, I need to select the entire list item when the user clicks on the side button so I can immediately remove it from the unorganized list. The issue that I am having is that I am trying to call something like $(this).find('font').text(); but this is only referring to the button that was clicked and not the entire list item. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking but it has been giving me grief for too long now.

The HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="friends" data-theme="a" 
data-divider- theme="a">
    <li data-role="list-divider"><h3>Friends</h3></li>
</ul>
```

The Javascript

```
    function getFriendsList(){
    var searchType = "friend";
    var friendList = "";
        var friendName = "";
        var friendPoints = "";
    var name = "";
    $.post('friendScript.php', {
        searchType : searchType,
    }, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            $.each(value, function(index, item){
            if(index == 0){
                friendName = item;
            }
            if(index == 1){
                friendGratii = item;
            }   
        });
        friendList += '<li class="friend"><a href=""><h3>' + 
                                  '<font id="friendsName">' + 
                                  friendName + 
                                  '</font>' + " - " + 
                                  friendPoints + 
                                  '</h3></a>' + 
                                  '<a href="" id="defriend" data-icon="delete">' +
                                  "Remove Friend " + '</a>' + '</li>';
    });
    $('#friends').append(friendList).listview('refresh');
            $('#friends').find('li:has(font)').find('#defriend')
            .unbind("click").bind("click",  
                function(){
        var clickedFriend = $(this);
            name = $(this).find('.friend').text(); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM IT 
                                                        //ALWAYS RETURNS AN EMPTY STRING
                        $.post('defriendScript.php', {
                friendName : name,
            }, function(data){
                if(data != "success"){
                alert(data);
                }
                if(data == "success"){
                    $(clickedFriend).remove();
                }
            });
        });
    }, "json"); 
    };
```

Comment: DANGER! You can't rely on removal by name. What happens if the database has two John Smiths or two Peter Jones? You have to work with unique UIDs, ie database keys.

Comment: the friends name is a unique username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
name = $(this).find('.friend').text();
```

`$(this)` will be the `#defriend` element, which is a child of your `<li>`. Doing `$(this).find('.friend')` will search for elements with class `friend` within your button. whichi is not what you want. Try this:

```
name = $(this).parent().text();
```

Comment: this worked for me I just added .find('font) after parent. I apprecaiate all of your quick responses and I wish I could have given the right answer to multiple answers. I knew there was an easy way to do this and I feel kinda dumb now that I see how simple it was.

Comment: It's a little dangerous using "parent", because it's brittle; refactoring the HTML layout just a little, and you break all of your javascript.  For better maintainability, I would recommend traversing up the DOM tree with ".closest()" and look for an element that wraps this entry.  Not perfect, just a little more robust :)

Answer (score 1):

$(this) will refer to the button that was clicked.

`$(this).find('something')` will look at HTML elements contained by the button.
`$(this).closest('something')` will look at HTML elements containing the button.
`$(this).siblings('something')` will look at HTML elements with the same direct parent of the button.

You probably want something like

```
$(this).siblings('font');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems. The main one is that `find` searches an element's descendants, not its siblings, and that's what you want. Another is that you're using multiple identical `id`s, which is wrong. So, here's a general cleanup with that fix included, at least a start:

```
function getFriendsList() {
    var searchType = "friend";
    var friendName = "";
    var friendPoints = "";

    $.post('friendScript.php', {
        searchType: searchType,
    }, function(data) {
        var friends = $('#friends');

        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            $.each(value, function(index, item) {
                if(index == 0) {
                    friendName = item;
                } else if(index == 1) {
                    friendGratii = item;
                }   
            });

            friends.append(
                $('<li>').addClass('friend')
                    .append(
                        $('<a>').prop('href', '#').append(
                            $('<h3>').append(
                                $('<span>').addClass('friendName').text(friendName),
                                ' - ',
                                friendPoints
                            )
                        ),
                        $('<a>').prop('href', '#').addClass('defriend').attr('data-icon', 'delete').text('Remove Friend')
                    )
            );
        });

        friends.listview('refresh');

        friends.find('.defriend').unbind('click').click(function(e) {
            var name = clickedFriend.prev('.friendName').text();

            $.post('defriendScript.php', {
                friendName: name
            }, function(data) {
                if(data === "success") {
                    $(clickedFriend).remove();
                } else {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }, "json");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ID's must be unique in a page, but you are re-using the same ones over. Chnage all your repeating ID's to class.

The button has no descendents for "find" to look for.

You might consider adding a data attribute to the button, or to the parent li.

```
<a href="#" class="defriend" data-icon="delete" data-friend="friend name here" >
```

Then in click handler:

```
var name= $(this).data('friend')
```